# C++ Console encerra sozinho, quando digitado numeros com virgula

Tags: c++

contas com numeros inteiros e float(com ponto) o programa faz a continha certinho e pergunta no final se desejo continuar

agora contas com numeros (com virgula) o programa simplesmente encerra, sem perguntar se desejo continuar

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int somar(float& a, float& b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    float num1;
    float num2;
    char continuar; // Variável para armazenar a escolha do usuário
   
    do
    {
        cout << "digite dois numeros a ser somado:  " << endl;
        cin >> num1 >> num2;
        bool verificar = num1;     // Apenas para verificar se o numero digitado é true ou false
        cout << verificar << endl; // apenas em teste
     
        
            if (num1 && num2)   // verifica se a variavel num1 e num2 se é  true (numero) ou false (caractere)
                cout << somar(num1, num2) << endl;

            else
            {
                cout << "numeros digitados sao zero" << endl;
                break; // sem esse break, entre em loop
            }
               
       /*
       
       Se o valor digitado pelo o usuario for com virgula(Ex 55,55)
       O programa se encerra imediatamente 

       */
    
    cout << "Deseja continuar? ";    
    cin >> continuar;

    } while (continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S'); // Continua se o usuário digitar 's' ou 'S'

    cout << "Programa encerrado." << endl;
    system("pause");
   
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: aconteceria  o mesmo com um 'y' ou um '?'.... Trata-se de um programa de computador esperando ler numeros. Mude o ponto decimal em seu sistema e ele vai aceitar a virgula e encerrar com o ponto. Pensou em mostrar os valores lidos, logo na linha seguinte? É bom quando se está aprendendo.

Comment: Use ponto o c++ não aceita virgulas no valores numericos.

Answer (score -5):

@Eduardo Faria   seu programa encerra sem perguntar se quer continuar é por causa do
break;
da condição do

```
if(num1 && num2);
    break;
```

onde o num2 terá o valor zero, pois o cin adiciona a parte válida do que foi digitado à variável "num1" e zero
em num2 , que é a parte inválida .
pois o compilador da linguagem c foi criado pelo americano "Dennis Ritchie", e por isso entende o modo de escrita do
idioma ingles onde os números com casas decimais são separados por ponto ,e você pode modificar esse idioma , por
qualquer outro que você queira , e até mesmo para o portugues , onde usamos vírgula como separador das casas
decimmais , usando para isso o header:

```
#include <locale.h> 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
```

e funcionará em computadores que tenha uma determinada configuração , mas em outros não , assim um modo mais fácil
é deixar o compilador usar o ponto mesmo, e no decorrer do programa fazer uma validação dos dados introduzidos pelo
usuário , e se for digitado números com vírgula substituir por ponto , assim  ficará no padrão certo do compilador ,
e para isso precisa usar três funçõeszinhas , a primeira é a "fgets" usada no lugar da função "cin" , onde irá
pegar os dados digitados e armazena los em uma string da linguagem c , que é formada por um vetor de caracteres ,
para fazer a verificação de cada digito do número digitado , e outra função é a "strstr" que, através de certa técnica,
pode ser usada para determinar a posição do caractere verificado na string e assim substituir a vírgula por ponto , e
outra é a função "atof" , que converte uma string em um número do tipo float , que pode ter casas decimais .
aqui um exemplo de seu código com essas modificações :

```
#define     _WIN32_WINNT 0x600
#define     _h GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
#include    <cstdlib>
#include    <windows.h>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <string>
#include    <cctype>
#include    <cfloat>
using namespace std;
float somar ( float, float                                  );
int main    ( int argc, char *argv[]                         )
{
    int letra,fundo;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO _c                            ;
    if( GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo     ( _h, & _c )          )
    {
        letra = (   _c.wAttributes & 0xFF )            & 0x0F;
        fundo = ( ( _c.wAttributes & 0xFF ) >> 4    )  & 0x0F;
    }
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( _h, 11 +       ( 0 << 4 )      );
    ///-------------------------------------------------------

    float num1    = 0.0;
    float num2    = 1.0;
    float vet[2]  = { };
    char  aux[10] = "3.141592";
    char  continuar ; /// Variável para armazenar a escolha do usuário
    do
    {
        cout << "digite dois numeros a ser somado:" << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
        {
            fflush(            stdin      );
            fgets ( aux, 9,    stdin      );
            char* p  = strstr( aux,   "," );
            if(   p  ) aux[p - aux] = '.'  ;
            vet[i]   = atof(   aux        );
        }
        num1  = vet[0];
        num2  = vet[1];
                                     /// bool tem apenas dois valores 1 (true) e 0 (false)
        bool verificar = num1;       /// Apenas para verificar se o numero
                                     /// digitado é true ou false
        cout << "val de verificar= " /// apenas em teste
             << verificar << endl;   /// ver se variavel num1 e num2 se eh
        if ( num1 && num2 )          /// true (diferente de Zero) ou false (iguaL a zeRo)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute( _h, 15 +       ( 12 << 4 )     );
            cout << " Resultado= "<< somar(num1, num2) << " " << endl;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute( _h, 11 +       ( 0 << 4 )      );
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Um ou Dois dos numeros digitados é zero" << endl;
            break;                   /// sem esse break, entre em loop
        }
        cout << "Deseja continuar? ";
        cin  >> continuar;
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');   // Continua se o usuário digitar 's' ou 'S'
    cout << "Programa encerrado." << endl;
    system("pause");

    ///-------------------------------------------------------
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( _h, letra +  ( fundo << 4 )    );
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return   0;
}
float somar( float a, float b ) /// funCAo int retorna int
{
    return a + b;
}
```